# Large size Video is not autoplay in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using video.play() for play the video on button click. but is not working in iPad for large video file. Sometime its working only for the small size video.

We are trying to autoplay video on the "next" button click, it is working fine in Desktop but creating issues in Ipad.

I have tired to use settimeout for play the video after sometime but nothing working for me in ipad.

Any Idea?

Comment: When you say 'not working' what exactly is happening? Is the video buffering before it plays, perhaps?

Comment: Not it not seems buffering, I have tested it. No loading or buffering action performs.